# stale state inside socket callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, use-state, use-ref

I was trying to make socket connection using React hooks. I am getting a stale value when trying to access a state variable inside socket callback function. `users` variable inside socket callback is not having the latest value. Using `useRef` works but it does not rerender the component. What could be the better solution for this ?. Thanks!

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
const result = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(`${config.host}?meetingId=${result.id}`);
    socket.request = promise(socket);
    setSocket(socket);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket) return;
    let webrtc = null;
    
    socket.on('UserLeft', ({ id }) => {
        setUsers(users => users.filter(user => user.id !== id))
    });

    socket.on('UserAdded', ({ name, id }) => {
        const newUser = new OtherUser(name, id);
        setUsers(users => [...users, newUser])
    })

    socket.on('newProducer', async (data) => {
        const { socketId, kind } = data;

        const consumer = await webrtc.createConsumer(socketId, kind);
        
        // Issue is here, the users array still has stale values
        const user = users.find(ele => ele.id === socketId);
        
        // Some more stuff with user
    })

}, [socket]);

// Here the output is correct
console.log(users)


return <div>HELLO</div>
```

Comment: You've enclosed the *current* state in the effect into the `onUserAdd` callback. Try defining that callback outside the effect, and wrap it in a `useCallback` hook with a dependency on `users`.

Comment: `useRef` seems to be the right direction. Can you add code with `useRef`?

Comment: @DrewReese tried that, still the same issue. Thanks anyway. @marzelin tried ```useRef```. Had to do a bit of hack to re-render the component but it's working Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useReducer` to store mutating variables and add logic into the handler